# Numeric Keyboard does not appear

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, keyboard, visual-studio-mac

I am building an app using Xamarin Forms. I have the following code for my keyboard:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,0,0,20">
        <Entry Keyboard="Numeric" HeightRequest="200" WidthRequest="200"/>
</StackLayout>
```

This is what appears on my app:

[image]

Will the keyboard appear using on XAML? Or do I need to use C# to make it appear? What's causing the keyboard to not show up?

Comment: the keyboard will appear when the Entry gets focus

Comment: How does the Entry get focus?

Comment: when the user selects it, or you call it's `Focus` method

Comment: While running in the simulator, I clicked it. That just brings up a cursor that allows text entry. But I do not have a Focus method for it yet.

Comment: if you are using iOS, check the Simulator menu to be sure you have the soft keyboard enabled

Comment: I did that, but it doesn't bring up the keyboard in that space. It's more of a pop-up, but I can work with that.

Comment: perhaps if you posted a screenshot of what is actually happening we could help you

Comment: I'm using VS for Mac. Turns out that I did actually enable the soft keyboard. I toggled the keyboard on.

Comment: Are you saying that you got it to work now?

Comment: The soft keyboard is a feature of the Apple iOS Emulator, not VS Mac

Comment: No, it's not working now. I was mistaken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a get method to the .cs file that is assigned to that particular xaml file.

```
public static Keyboard Numeric { get; }
```

The keyboard appears when I click on the area pictured above.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this answer cannot possibly fix the symptom.

Comment: It worked for me.

Comment: I’m glad your keyboard is working now. I’m saying, for your learning and for anyone else who reads this Q&A in the future, that line of code cannot have any effect on the code shown in the question. Its literally impossible. It happens to have the words keyboard and Numeric, but not in a way that would be seen by that XAML. The real problem was something else - maybe you just needed a Rebuild, and *any* change would have made it work. OR there is something else in your page’s XAML that needed that addition - impossible to know without seeing the entire XAML of the page. Just FYI.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the problem. Here is code that works - what is different from yours? You'll need to experiment with changes to your code, to find out what exactly is causing the problem.

You can [download the repo](https://github.com/ToolmakerSteve/TestXFBugs). See [SoftKeyboardEntryPage](https://github.com/ToolmakerSteve/TestXFBugs/blob/master/TestBugs/SoftKeyboardEntryPage.xaml). In [project TestBugs, file App.xaml.cs](https://github.com/ToolmakerSteve/TestXFBugs/blob/master/TestBugs/App.xaml.cs), be sure to set `MainPage = new SoftKeyboardEntryPage();`.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TestBugs.SoftKeyboardEntryPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Entry Keyboard="Numeric" Text="Test" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="200" BackgroundColor="Pink"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

When I click in the pink area, the numeric keyboard appears.

When I click in the white area, the keyboard goes away.

---

Also, when the app is running in iOS simulator, on Simulator's menu bar at top of Mac screen, try toggling `IO / Keyboard / Toggle Soft Keyboard` on and off. Does that have any effect?

Maybe also UNCHECK `Connect Hardware Keyboard` - though for me the soft keyboard appears even when the Mac's keyboard is connected.

However, I couldn't find any situation where the Soft Keyboard failed to show up, regardless of those settings.

Tested with simulator running iPhone 13 Pro, iOS 15.0.